# Certificate imported via Azure Portal not found in Personal store

Tags: azure, certificate

We have a cloud service in Azure, in which we used the `Certificates` setting, in Azure Portal, to upload a cert file `.pfx`. Once the upload is complete, the cert appears in the list of certiifcates.

However, when we remote onto either of the boxes for this cloud service, and use `mmc` to open the `Certificates` snap-in, at the local computer level, the cert is not found in any location.

We have used PowerShell to perform a `dir` in the `cert:` location, and simply cannot see that cert anywhere, even though it appears in the list of certs in Azure. We have two instances of the site running - the cert file is not found on either instance.

I'm unsure what we have missed here. I assumed that uploading a cert file via the Azure Portal would take care of importing the cert into the instance boxes?

Can someone help out please?

Comment: Did you make necessary changes in your Cloud Service configuration (cscfg) & service definition (csdef) files and referenced that certificate there? Please see this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313831/how-to-reference-x-509-certificates-on-a-cloud-service-deployed-on-azure/41316151#41316151.

Comment: Awesome. I will take a look at that. Sounds promising.

Comment: Certificates will not be distributed to role instances unless they are listed in the .cscfg.

Comment: @GauravMantri That information worked a treat. I re-deployed the cloud service, after adding the appropriate `<certificate>` elements to the service definition, and config files, and it looks like the cert is now correctly installed. If you place your comment as an answer, I will go ahead and accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked fine for you. If you don't mind, I would rather close this question as a duplicate of the one I linked. Please let me know.